# Keyboard accelerator firing when writing to Textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image]

Click event of `Button` is fired when pressing <kbd>D</kbd> while writing to `Textbox`.

Is there an elegant way **how to suppress Keyboard Accelerator** while `Textbox` is focused?

**XAML:**

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button with &quot;D&quot; as keyboard accelerator" Margin="0,10">
       <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
           <KeyboardAccelerator Key="D"></KeyboardAccelerator>
       </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonClickCounter"></TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```

**C#:**

```
    int buttonClickCounter;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClickCounter.Text = $"Button clicked {++buttonClickCounter} times";
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Why Accelerator with Modifier (Alt+D or Ctrl+D) is not solution?

- I am creating video player and I found that one-key shortcuts are neat solution for fast operations with video player (same as in VLC).

**Best Solution so far:**
Creating custom `KeyboardAccelerator`, that checks if focus is set to text box. Only edit in code that need to be done is changing `KeyboardAccelerator` to `AcceleratorWithHandledActionIfTextboxIsFocused`.

```
public  class AcceleratorWithHandleDActionIfTextboxIsFocused:KeyboardAccelerator
{
    public AcceleratorWithHandleActionIfTextboxIsFocused()
    {
       Invoked += AcceleratorWithHandleActionIfTextboxIsFocused_Invoked;
    }

    private void AcceleratorWithHandleActionIfTextboxIsFocused_Invoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
        if (focusedElement.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

part of XAML:

```
<Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
   <custom:AcceleratorWithHandleDActionIfTextboxIsFocused Key="D"></KeyboardAccelerator>
</Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
```

Comment: One would not use D as an acceleration key, but Alt+D or Ctrl+D

Comment: Yes, of course. But it is not the option for this case, neither the solution...

Comment: Hello, how do you use ALT as a modifier? It is not an option, right? How do you work around with it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Thomas Weller in his comments as for not using a single letter as a keyboard accelerator...
But everybody has their own requirements, anyway,  you could try to e.handle = true your event when textbox is focused.

Something like this:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (textBox.isFocused)
   {
      e.handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is far from elegant solution.. Imagine all the textboxes and buttons... But your answer actually inspire me..

Comment: If this is a requirement of all the buttons and textboxes in your solution, you can have your controls inherit from the actual textbox and button and perform your validation globally in the parent control.